# What is the difference between masking and tolerating failures?

Tags: distributed-systems, fault-tolerance

*Distributed Systems* 5ed by Coulouris says on p21-22

> **1.5.5 Failure handling**
>
> **Detecting failures**: Some failures can be detected. For example, checksums can be  used to detect corrupted data in a message or a
>   file. Chapter 2 explains that it is  difficult or even impossible to
>   detect some other failures, such as a remote crashed  server in the
>   Internet. The challenge is to manage in the presence of failures that 
>   cannot be detected but may be suspected.
>
> **Masking failures**: Some failures that have been detected can be hidden or made less  severe. Two examples of hiding failures:
>
> 1. Messages can be retransmitted when they fail to arrive.
> 2. **File data can be written to a pair of disks** so that if one is corrupted, the other may still be correct.
>
> Just dropping a message that is corrupted is an example of making a
>   fault less severe –  it  could  be  retransmitted.  The  reader  will 
>   probably  realize  that  the  techniques  described  for  hiding 
>   failures  are  not  guaranteed  to  work  in  the  worst  cases;  for 
>   example, the data on the second disk may be corrupted too, or the
>   message may not  get through in a reasonable time however often it is
>   retransmitted.
>
> **Tolerating failures**: Most of the services in the Internet do exhibit failures – it would not be practical for them to attempt to
>   detect and hide all of the failures that might  occur  in  such  a 
>   large  network  with  so  many  components.  Their  clients  can  be 
>   designed to tolerate failures, which generally involves the users
>   tolerating them as  well. For example, when a web browser cannot
>   contact a web server, it does not make  the user wait for ever while
>   it keeps on trying – it informs the user about the problem,  leaving
>   them free to try again later. Services that tolerate failures are
>   discussed in the  paragraph on **redundancy** below.
>
> **Recovery from failures**: Recovery involves the design of software so that the state of  permanent  data  can  be  recovered  or  ‘rolled
>   back’  after  a  server  has  crashed.  In  general, the computations
>   performed by some programs will be incomplete when a  fault occurs,
>   and the permanent data that they update (files and other material
>   stored  in  permanent  storage)  may not  be  in  a consistent state. 
>   Recovery  is  described in  Chapter 17.
>
> **Redundancy**: Services  can  be  made  to  tolerate  failures  by  the  use  of  redundant  components. Consider the following examples:
>
> 1. There should always be at least two different routes between any two routers in  the Internet.
> 2. In  the  Domain  Name  System,  every  name  table  is  replicated  in  at  least  two  different servers.
> 3. A database may be replicated in several servers to ensure that the data remains  accessible after the failure of any single server; the
>      servers can be designed to  detect  faults  in  their  peers;  when  a
>      fault  is  detected  in  one  server,  clients  are  redirected to the
>      remaining servers.

What is the difference between masking and tolerating failures?

Can they both be done by redundancy? (The quote seems to say so. Then what differences are between them?)

Do they both need to perform recovery from failures?

Thanks.

Comment: Masking vs tolerating: What explanation do you expect beyond what the book says?

Comment: Going by your quote from the book, I would say masking a failure is when TCP re-sends a dropped packet, while tolerating a failure is when too many packets get dropped and Chrome times out and shows you the dinosaur game.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg (1) what is not tolerating a failure then, if showing dinosaur game is tolerating? (2) Why is replication  mentioned in both masking and tolerating faliures, if the two are distinctly different?

Comment: @Tim Not tolerating a failure might include crashing or exposing a security vulnerability because another process or remote computer failed.

Comment: I have no idea why the examples listed under "redundancy" are considered "tolerating" rather than "masking", though.

Answer (score 2):

The source of your misunderstanding may be that you think the excerpt contains a list of methods to handle system failures that are mutually exclusive.  Masking and tolerating failures often happen simultaneously depending on the interface one part of a system presents to another.

Example: a word processor application might only care whether a document was written successfully to the file system.  It doesn't care about all the underlying storage failure modes there might be, so the operating system *masks* them and only reports whether the file was written successfully.  Meanwhile, the disk controller *tolerates* some types of read and write errors, masking them from the operating system, retrying soft read errors and remapping logical disk blocks away from problem areas on the disks.  A RAID controller might sit between the operating system and individual disk controllers, checksumming data and repairing blocks before they reach the operating system.

I think the point of the excerpted paragraphs is to make the reader aware of the kinds of choices a system designer has to make, and how those choices depend greatly on the interface to the system that the designer has to present.